Magento 2 : Existing "category_ids" missing on product edit page
We have recently updated our magento version from 2.2.11 to 2.4.6-p5 and bumped into the issue below.
After the new version is installed on our production website, "category_ids" can not be displayed at all on product edit page as you can see in the screenshot below. But if we check from category page on backend as well as catalog_category_product on database, all products still have the correct caregories.
So far we have done the followings to try to fix this issue but have not found any solutions unfortunately:

Added a new product with caregory -> after saving it, we can see the product in category page on backend as well as catalog_category_product on database BUT we can still not see it on product edit page
Simply saved a product without category being displayed on product edit page -> all existing categories with the product are deleted from the product saved
Checked eav_attribute table if any values are changed -> Identical before and after the update was made

If any of you have had the same issue in the past, your cooperation would be much appreciated.

・Record for category_ids on catalog_eav_attribute

・Category is also not displayed on Product Grid


When open the product page any error on log file or console?

Thank you for your message. No error when opening the product page at all.

Try to disable all third party extension and then check.

You should reindex  your store if you haven't already. If you are still facing the issue. the issue might be with data in path or level column of your catalog_category_entity table.

You should check if the is_visible column in catalog_eav_attribute corresponding to category_ids row is set to 0. If it is, setting it 1 should  fix your issue.
Get attribute id of category_ids attribute using following query;
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'category_ids';

Now check if the entry corresponding to it has is_visible set to 0 using following query;
select * from catalog_eav_attribute where attribute_id = {attribute_id you got from previous query};

Or you can just combine both the queries and check the result of following query;
select is_visible from catalog_eav_attribute where attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'category_ids');


It is set at 1 already. I added an image in the original post.

Hmm, which store scope are you checking right now? Does it say "All Store Views"?

Yep. Scope: All Store Views shown on top left and right below product name on product edit page.

That maybe the problem, set the store scope to "Default" and the categories should show up.

Ahh, I was thinking of a different store where categories were set to store scope not global scope. This might not be it.

Switching to Default Store View did not solve but thank you for your insight!
